# Django Admin how to show ID of Items in List

Tags: django, django-admin

Here is what i see in my Django Admin:

The model Topic has 4 fields in it.

```
class TopicModel(models.Model):
    strid = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    code = models.TextField()
```

It's not convenient to see topics list as a
TopicModel object (1)
TopicModel object (2)
TopicModel object (3)

Is there a setup to show fields values (for example 'name') in the list like:

TopicModel name1
TopicModel name2
TopicModel name3

I'm sure should be some setup for this in Django, Please notify me if it's possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what your looking for. For more info about model instance reference checkout the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#other-model-instance-methods)

```
class TopicModel(models.Model):
        strid = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        description = models.TextField()
        code = models.TextField()

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)
```